# Ehrenfest paradox and the link to general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, rotational-kinematics, history

I've seen several sources stating that Einstein was partially inspired by the Ehrenfest paradox when thinking about general relativity. However in the Ehrenfest paradox the non-Euclidean nature of the space in the rotating frame of reference is linked to Lorentz contraction rather than gravitational forces like in GR. Is the link simply that the rotating disk question got Einstein thinking about non-Euclidean geometry as a way to treat non-inertial reference frames?

Comment: This might be better migrated to history of science and mathematics SE.

Comment: It is not possible to know what Einstein was inspired by unless we have his own statements. Can you give citations of the sources that make this statement? I am kind of interested to know where these suggestions come from. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to demonstrate that c is a constant Einstein needed to show that two coincidental light beams moving in opposite directions to one another still have the velocity of c (one in reference to the other), and not 2c as Euclidian calculations would dictate. To do that, a new approach needed to be demonstrated and this was the reason for Minkowsky/Einstein adaptation of Riemann non-Euclidian geometry. While the Einstein's application of non-Euclidian geomertry preceeded the Ehrenfest Paradox its full subsequent development was stimulated in part by Ehrenfest's paradox.

Comment: That c is constant is not needed anywhere in special relativity, though. It's a superfluous assumption.

Comment: @FlatterMann The second postulate of special relativity is that "light is always propagated in empty space with a definite velocity c that is independent of the state of motion of the emitting body" So how according to you c constant in not needed "anywhere" in special relativity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postulates_of_special_relativity

Answer (score 0):

In 1907 (2 years after the theory of special relativity was published), Einstein came up with his equivalence principle. It basically states a free falling observer in a gravitational field is equivalent locally to a inertial observer in flat space and importantly that an observer with artificial acceleration in flat space is equivalent to a stationary observer in a gravitational field. Einstein realised this principle was a key stepping stone from SR to GR and a 'keeper'.

In 1909, the Ehrenfest paradox was introduced. Rather than providing clarity and inspiration this paradox caused no end of confusion and arguments (and still does). It basically states that no object can be spun up in a Born rigid manner. No progress was made on the theory of general relativity over the next three years after the introduction of the Ehrenfest paradox.

In 1912 Einstein considered observers on a rotating disk and put aside worries about how the disk was spun up and just considered a disk that was already spinning with constant angular rotation. (Real life observations indicate that extended objects can in fact be brought from rest to a state of rotation.)

In his rotating disk thought experiment, Einstein considered the measurements by accelerated observers of the perimeter versus the measurements of the radius and realised the geometry is non Euclidean. It is inconceivable that Einstein would not have made the connection between what the accelerated observers measured and what observers in a gravitational field would observe, because that is made clear by his beloved equivalence principle.

It is historically recorded that the rotating disk thought experiment made Einstein realise he had to get to grips with non Euclidean geometry to make progress. This [Wikipedia article on Einstein's thought experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%27s_thought_experiments) states:

> Einstein realized that he did not have the mathematical skills to
> describe the non-Euclidean view of space and time that he envisioned,
> so he turned to his mathematician friend, Marcel Grossmann, for help.
> After researching in the library, Grossman found a review article by
> Ricci and Levi-Civita on absolute differential calculus (tensor
> calculus). Grossman tutored Einstein on the subject, and in 1913 and
> 1914, they published two joint papers describing an initial version of
> a generalized theory of gravitation

This makes it clear that the rotating disk thought experiment motivated Einstein to study non Euclidean geometry and this was the key in making the final step from SR to GR, which followed shortly after.

It also states:

> Such a system K, according to the equivalence principle, is strictly
> equivalent to a system at rest in which a matter-free static
> gravitational field of a certain kind exists.

and

> In later years, Einstein repeatedly stated that consideration of the
> rapidly rotating disk was of "decisive importance" to him because it
> showed that a gravitational field causes non-Euclidean arrangements of
> measuring rods

The OP asks:

> the non-Euclidean nature of the space in the rotating frame of
> reference is linked to Lorentz contraction rather than gravitational
> forces like in GR - Simon Mackenzie

While there is no gravity in the rotating disk thought experiment, the equivalence principle clearly hints the observations of accelerated observers are closely related to the observation of observers in a gravitational field. How those measurements come about is immaterial. There is more to the thought experiment than length contraction. There is an effective field potential on the rotating disk, with the force experienced by the accelerated observers increasing proportional to $\omega^2R$ with increasing distance from the centre and that there is also a connection between the increased time dilation experienced by the accelerated observer's relative to their location in this artificial acceleration field.

It can also be noted that if an observer at the centre of a rotating disk measures the radius to be R using radar measurement, then the accelerated observer on the perimeter will measure the radius to be <R. It turns out that the same is true in a gravitational field, where an observer lower down measures the radar distance to the observer above him as less than the radar distance measured by the higher observer.

> Is the link simply that the rotating disk question got Einstein
> thinking about non-Euclidean geometry as a way to treat non-inertial
> reference frames? - Simon Mackenzie

Basically, yes, the history suggests that.